# SQL: capture start and end of 2 weeks ahead

Tags: sql-server

I've looked through the similar questions and none of them seem to capture my use case.

What I'm needing to do is identify the start and end days of 2 weeks ahead, irrespective of the day of the week "today" might be. Note, weeks in this scenario start with Sunday and end with Saturday.

For example, the week of 12/11/2022 - 12/17/2022, let's say "today" is 12/13. I need my @Start and @End to be 12/25 and 12/31 respectively. Similarly, I need this same output if "today" were to fall on any day in that week (12/11 - 12/17).

The solution I was using previously involved the use of the week of the year a given date lived in and adding 2 to that number to identify my date range, but where I came up short of course was when the new year started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DATEPART` and `DATEADD` functions to achieve what you want, here is an example using your example date of `2022-12-13`, but it will work for any valid date:

```
declare @today date = '2022-12-13'; --returns start: 2022-12-25, end: 2022-12-31
--declare @today date = '2022-12-26'; --returns start: 2023-01-08, end: 2023-01-14

--Check what day of the week the date you are working with is,
--if it's not Sunday, subtract days to get the current week's Sun. date
IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @today) = 3
    SET @today = DATEADD(day, -2, @today);
ELSE IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @today) = 4
    SET @today = DATEADD(day, -3, @today);
ELSE IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @today) = 5
    SET @today = DATEADD(day, -4, @today);
ELSE IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @today) = 6
    SET @today = DATEADD(day, -5, @today);
ELSE IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @today) = 7
    SET @today = DATEADD(day, -6, @today);
ELSE IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @today) = 2
    SET @today = DATEADD(day, -1, @today);

--add 14 days to the current week Sun date
declare @startdate date = DATEADD(day, 14, @today);
--add 6 days to the desired start date
declare @enddate date = DATEADD(day, 6, @startdate);

select @startdate, @enddate
```

Comment: Ah I think I understand. So basically, you're reassigning "today" as that week's Sunday and then doing simple dateadd's to get the corresponding start and end range. I may try to translate it into a CASE, but I dig it, it's a clever solution, thank you!

Comment: @jw11432 That's exactly what I am doing and I'm glad it was helpful. :)